# JQuery optimization for searching classes

Tags: jquery, optimization

I have some filters on the left. Each filter has an id. The id of that filter is used to filter some results that have the id of the filter in their classes.

Filters refer to characteristics of products.. example

```
<a id="filter_colorRED">RED</a>

...

<li id="item4" class="filter_colorBLUE">Blah Blah</li>
<li id="item5" class="filter_colorRED ">Blah Blah</li>
<li id="item6" class="filter_colorRED filter_colorBLACK">Blah Blah</li>
```

I am looking for the best method to find which filters should be disabled. Disabled filters  should be these that dont exist in visible items' classes.

For example if colorBlue is applied RED and BLACK should be disabled because the only `<li>` that has the BLUE class doesn't contain RED or BLACK.

My only thought is for each filter to check against results `.hasclass(filter's id)` but I think that this is poor. Any other idea?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about. Please describe your problem better. And do not talk about "filter" when you mean "CSS class", that's confusing.

Comment: Can you provide the markup? After reading this 3 times I'm not sure what you're after either.

Comment: @Parhs: So if the user clicks on `<a id="filter_colorRED">`, all but `li.filter_colorRED` should disappear?

Comment: I see that code i wrote dissapeared.. Yes tomalak,but this should work even if it has more than 1 classes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple approach:

```
$("a").click(function () {
  $("li").hide().hasClass(this.id).show();
});
```

Optionally you can choose a variant:

```
$("a").click(function () {
  var a = this;
  $("li").toggle(function() { return $(this).hasClass(a.id); });
});
```

`toggle()` accepts a function that returns true or false in order to show or hide an element. You could do some more complex calculations in the `toggle()` function. If you just check for `hasClass()`, the first approach is the better one.